# Am trying to parse data from a dynamic html form with javascript or jquery to php and insert the data into the database

Tags: javascript, php

I have an html form with three input fields which I increment dynamically with javascript. I have to parse the data to PHP which I have done but I can't access the data and insert it into the database as this is an array data. I have tried but it's not working.

Here is my code:

**html and Javascript**

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="othername[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="lastName[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_last" /></td>
              <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
  $('#add').click(function(){
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="otherName[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_last" /></td><td><input type="text" name="lastName[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_last" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
    $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
  });

  $('#submit').click(function(){    
    $.ajax({
      url:"name.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
      success:function(data)
      {
        alert(data);
        $('#add_name')[0].reset();
      }
    });
  });

});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```php
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$number = count($_POST["name"]);
$numberx = count($_POST["othername"]);
$numbers = count($_POST["lastname"]);
if($number > 1 && $numbers > 1){

    for(($i=0; $i<$number; $i++) && ($x=0; $x<$numberx; $x++) && ($w=0; $w<$numbers; $w++)){

        if(trim($_POST["name"][$i] != '') && trim($_POST["othername"][$x] != '') && 
             trim($_POST["lastname"][$w] != '')){

            $namex      = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name"][$i]);
            $othernamex = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["othername"][$x]);
            $lastnamex  = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["lastname"][$w]);

            $check = "INSERT INTO bl_name (name, othername, lastname) VALUES ('$namex', '$othernamex', '$lastnamex')";
            mysqli_query($connect, $check);
        }
    }
    echo "Data Inserted";
}
else
{
    echo "Please Enter Name";
}
```

I need help as I have been on this for two days now. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Just as a heads up: You're vulnerable to sql injection. Please use prepared statements to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your input names, change them to:

```
user[][name]
user[][othername]
user[][lastname]
```

Run a simple `foreach()` loop on `$_POST['user']`:

```
foreach($_POST['user'] as $user){
    $namex      = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $user["name"]);
    $othernamex = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $user["othername"]);
    $lastnamex  = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $user["lastname"]);

    $check = "INSERT INTO bl_name (name, othername, lastname) VALUES ('{$namex}', '{$othernamex}', '{$lastnamex}')";
    mysqli_query($connect, $check); 
}
```

Keep in mind that form field names are case sensitive. You're also not testing if the `mysqli_query()` function returns successfully. You should probably do that. And yes, prepared statements are safer.

Comment: Thanks am trying it out the speed is awesome

Comment: Please I have tried this out and I have all I can but it not working, please can you expand on it please be clear @Dearsina

Comment: When you say "not working", what do you mean? What kind of output are you getting?